# How to add animations in Jvector maps

Tags: animation, jvectormap

I want to create a map which looks like http://map.honeynet.org/

I am able to add the markers in the jvector maps and it looks like this.

[image: world map]
 Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>World Map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/aravi/heatmap/jvector/jvectormaps/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="/home/aravi/heatmap/jvector/jvectormaps/tests/assets/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="/home/aravi/heatmap/jvector/jvectormaps/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/home/aravi/heatmap/jvector/jvectormaps/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="world-map-markers" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px; margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 38px;"> </div>
  <script>
   $(function(){
  $('#world-map-markers').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,

    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
    fill: 'red',
    r: '3',
    stroke: '#383f47'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'},
      {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
      {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
      {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
      {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
      {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
      {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
      {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
      {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
      {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
      {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
      {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
      {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
      {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
      {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
      {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
      {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
      {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
      {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
      {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
      {latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati'},
      {latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga'},
      {latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica'},
      {latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius'},
      {latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain'},
      {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
    ]
  });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me in how to add the animation into the map.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its almost 3 weeks and still no response. Luckily got this which explains the working of honeynet map. https://github.com/fw42/honeymap
After a lot of reading implemented the same in google maps. http://jsbin.com/ivedix/2/edit